# OpenCL: State space mismatch between instruction and address

Tags: c++, opencl, ptxas

I'm writing a OpenCL program and on build I get this error:

```
Build Log:
ptxas application ptx input, line 268; error   : State space mismatch between instruction and address in instruction 'ld'
ptxas application ptx input, line 269; error   : State space mismatch between instruction and address in instruction 'ld'
ptxas application ptx input, line 270; error   : State space mismatch between instruction and address in instruction 'ld'
ptxas application ptx input, line 271; error   : State space mismatch between instruction and address in instruction 'ld'
....(same error on several more lines)
```

The corresponding ptx lines (auto-generated) are:

```
ld.local.u32    %r1913, [demands$inst_to_cust+16];
ld.local.u32    %rl10, [demands$inst_to_cust+12];
ld.local.u32    %rl12, [demands$inst_to_cust+8];
ld.local.u32    %rl14, [demands$inst_to_cust+4];
ld.local.u32    %rl16, [demands$inst_to_cust];
```

Here's the function I've written :

```
int
demands(cl_ushort ball, cl_ushort bin,
    __global const struct problem *problem,
    __constant const struct demand *demand,
    const cl_ushort soln[BALL_MAXNUM],
    struct demand_op ops[DEMAND_MAXOPS],
    __global cl_ushort debug_data[DEBUG_LEN])
{
int i, k = demand->data[0]; 
int serv_to_rack[] = {0, 1, 1}; 
int inst_to_cust[] = {0, 0, 0, 1, 1}; 
int maxinst_per_rack[] = {2, 1}; 

int cust_num = inst_to_cust[ball];
int max = ball, min = ball, count = 1;
int max_in_rack = maxinst_per_rack[cust_num];
for (i = ball; i < NUM_BALLS; i++) {
    if (inst_to_cust[i] == ball) max = i;
    else break;
}

.....
}
```

What is the reason for the error? How can it be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is confused as to the location of the `demand` struct. "state space" is ptx-talk for memory type. `ld.local` expects the source to be in local memory, but in your case, it looks like it is actually in constant memory.

I'm not familiar with OpenCL, but in CUDA the `__constant__` qualifier places variables in constant memory, which has special caching semantics. It's not related to `const` in C++. It may be that the compiler is confused because you're using them together.

Try removing one or both of `__constant` and `const` from the `__constant const struct demand *demand` line.

Comment: Why so you think that the error is related to the `demand` struct? The assembly language translation seems to indicate that the problem is related to the `inst_to_cust` array.

Comment: You're right. I missed the "s" in demands. Then I don't see why you get the error. Have you tried removing the initialization array from the `inst_to_cust` declaration, just to see if it makes a difference?

Comment: Good Suggestion - moving the initialization from the declaration did fix the problem. Only thing is that now the initialization looks like `maxinst_per_rack[0] = 2; maxinst_per_rack[1] = 1;` etc. which does not look good (elegant), especially when I use longer arrays. Also, I have no clue why moving the initialization fixes the problem.

Comment: It looks like a compiler bug to me. It's as if the compiler puts the entire array in constant memory just because it was initialized with a list of constants.

Comment: It looks like the initialization values are specific to one instance of the problem the algorithm is solving, not to general instances? If so, maybe this particular issue will go away when your algorithm becomes more complete and you set it up to handle general instances of the problem.